# Manage access to file within a flow

Tags: workflow, access, flow, share, restricted-access

What I am trying to do is remove access to all groups and users but make the user that triggered the flow the owner and be the only one with access to that document.

Is this possible without using any external tools? I haven't found anything within flow that allows me to play with file permissions/access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a few SharePoint Http requests to the REST api. The first one to break the document's permission inheritance, another one to get the current user's ID from the SharePoint user list and the last one to set the permissions.

The library title is in the variable `myLibrary`, the document ID is in the variable `myDocumentID`.  Create a SharePoint HTTP request, select the site and set the method to `POST`. The URI will then look like this

```
_api/lists/getByTitle('@{variables('myLibrary')}')/items(@{variables('myDocumentID')})/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false,clearSubscopes=true)
```

Next, get the ID of the user that you want to assign permissions to. If this is run on a document library when a file is uploaded, you can get the user details from the ModifiedBy field. Use the Email address of that user and store it in the variable `UserEmail`. Then you can get their ID this way

SharePoint HTTP Request called `GetUserFromEmail', specify site, method is`GET`, URI is

```
_api/web/SiteUsers/getByEmail('@{variables('UserEmail')}')
```

This will return a complex user object. You need the `d.ID` property. Set the variable `CurrentUserID` to this expression

```
=body('GetUserFromEmail')['d']['ID']
```

Important: if the action to get the user contains spaces, the body() command must use underscores in place of the spaces for this to work.

```
=body('Action_with_spaces_are_harder_to_work_with')['d']['ID']
```

Now you can set the item permissions. Add a SharePoint HTTP request, select the site and set the method to `POST`. The URI is

```
_api/lists/getByTitle('@{variables('myLibrary')}')/items(@{variables('myDocumentID')})/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=@{variables('CurrentUserID')} ,roledefid=1073741830)
```

The `roledefid` for Edit permissions is above. Contribute would be `1073741827`. The standard roledefids can be easily found on the web. If you have custom permissions, you can find all permission numbers when you look at the xml returned by this URL.

```
https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yourSite/_api/web/roledefinitions
```

Let me know how you get on with this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I will try this in the next few days and let you know if it works.

Comment: Hi teylyn,

Thanks again for your response. It seems to work for everything except for the owner and users the document has been shared with manually. Is there a simple way to remove access from those users as well?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain in a bit more detail what is not working? You said you wanted to remove ALL ACCESS to the file, then give access to the current user. Is that not working? If your requirements have changed, please accept this as the answer to your original question and ask a new question with your new requirements.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, the requirements have not changed. I do want to remove all access from everyone associated with the document and make the user who triggered the flow the owner.  It just seems that when a user has modified access to the document and granted another user access manually, breakroleinheritance doesn't seem to work and no longer removes access from anyone (this could very well be an issue with our configuration). Still that being said it works fine for 90% of my scenarios.  Thank you very much! I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question :)